# Same connection file works for 1 script but not the other

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a directory with 2 php files in it. One is using an old way of querying a DB and the other can't even tell me if the connection exists.

**the connection file:** *(I've left out the actual credentials for obvious reasons)*

```
<?php
    # FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
    # Type="MYSQL"
    # HTTP="true"
    $hostname_student_dirR = "some_hostname";
    $database_student_dirR = "some_db_name";
    $username_student_dirR = "some_username";
    $password_student_dirR = "some_password";

    $student_dirR = new mysqli($hostname_student_dirR, $username_student_dirR, $password_student_dirR, $database_student_dirR) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

**file that successfully connects:**

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/student_diriR.php'); ?>

<?php
    mysqli_select_db($student_dirR, $database_student_dirR);
    $query_rs_get = "SELECT some_column FROM directory";
    $rs_get = mysqli_query($student_dirR, $query_rs_get) or die(mysqli_error($student_dirR));
    $row_rs_get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_get);
    $totalRows_rs_get = mysqli_num_rows($rs_get);
?>
```

**file that does NOT connect:** *(in the exact same directory as the file that does connect, so that path can't be the issue)*

```
<?php require_once("../Connections/student_dirR.php"); ?>

<?php
    if($student_dirR) echo "we're connected!";
    else echo "we're NOT connected!"; exit;
?>
```

The error message I get says "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in Connections/student_dirR.php:9"

Line 9 uses new mysqli() not mysql_connect(), so I don't know what that's talking about.

Comment: @Dharman no the message is not clear. the error says mysql_connect and if you actually read through the connection file I listed you'd see I'm using `new mysqli()` not `mysql_connect()` but no worries, someone else has already pointed out there was a spelling error. thanks anyway

Comment: Ok, sorry, I thought the spelling was intentional, and it threw me off. :)

Comment: In the snippets you posted, one requires a file named `student_diriR.php`, and the other includes a file named `student_dirR.php`. Is this intentional, or a typo?

Comment: BTW, `if($student_dirR)` is not a good way to check for a successful connection if you've created the connection using `new mysqli(...)`. `new mysqli` will always create a mysqli object, even if the connection failed, and an object is never false. You need to check connect_error instead. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php#refsect1-mysqli.construct-examples

Comment: @KyleWillmon did you notice the accepted answer?

Comment: For the record, this discussion was concluded in a [related meta post.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385785/should-i-pay-attention-to-answers-when-in-the-triage-review-queue?cb=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you have the spelling mistake in your directory name `student_diriR.php` and
`student_driR.php` that's why the error says `Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`. 
 see the difference below

file that successfully connects:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/student_diriR.php'); ?>
```

file that does NOT connect:

```
<?php require_once("../Connections/student_dirR.php"); ?>
```